# Initiating List<String> inside of AsyncTask in Android

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'm trying to initiate `List<String>` inside of `AsyncTask` and the whole task is no longer called, no errors though.

Just to be clear, the only reason I am after the `List` is that it gives me an opportunity to cut big chunk of elements at once using `sublist`.

If there's an easy way or you spotted a bug, please share.

```
protected void updateTask()
{
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
     {
         public void run() 
         {
                PatternTask myTask = new PatternTask();
                myTask.execute();
         }
     });
}
private class PatternTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    int eyes_closed;
    int eyes_opened;
    int eyes_avarage;

    String response = "NO DATA";
    protected String doInBackground(String... patterns) {
          String[] looper = getPattern().split("\n");
          List<String> patternList = new ArrayList<String>();
          for (int i = 0; i < looper.length; i++)
          {
             patternList.add(looper[i]); 
          }

          if (patternList.size() > 1200)
          {
                patternList.subList(0, patternList.size() - 1200).clear();
                ...
                ... 
          }
          else
                return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(FdActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
        }       
}
```

Comment: Well for one you're not passing any patterns into your `execute()` method.

Comment: Did you just add parameters to `doInBackground` that Android does not know about? Then the method won't be called. Why do you have an `@Override` only on the other method?

Comment: getPattern() is a getter passing String in, and when I won't use ArrayList inside, it is nicely doing so without the need of passing anything via execute(), this is why I'm confused. What's with this Arrays ?